# How to make fields appear required (by colouring)

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

Suppose, I have some required module attributes that cannot be made **required** for reasons that would conflict with certain actions such as duplicate. That these attributes are required, can be easily overcome during creation by raising ValidationErrors.

However, I would like to adjust the field parameters in the xml files form view to make these fields appear to the user in blue (as if they were required).

PS

I have tried all of the following

```
<field name="name" bgcolor="blue" fgcolor="red" color="black" colors="purple"/>
```

just to see if any of them would work.

I have also reset the local server and updated the module itself, thinking that maybe the xml files are not always reloaded on server-reset.

Any ideas on custom colouring fields in form-view would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add them as classes like this:

```
<field name="name" class="red"/>

.red {
    background:red;
    /* additional css here */
}
```

Comment: I like that this actually made something happen, although this background made it appear a little differently than I was hoping for. It kind made the entire field excluding the actual selection box a different colour

Comment: This was definitely the correct approach. Although required a much deeper understanding of css.

Answer (score 0):

You should write those attributes to tree tag like this:

```
<tree colors="black" bgcolor="yellow:name == other" string="Invoice">
    <field name="name" />
    <field name="other" />
</tree>
```

[Example from odoo source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account_payment/account_payment_view.xml#L155)

> In .xml side <, >, <=, >=, & is not supported. So we need to use `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;=` `&gt;=`, and `&amp;`

Comment: I like this approach although, I was hoping to do something like this in the form view...

Answer (score 0):

XML attributes on "official nodes" are validated, you cannot add them as you like. When developing `web_field_style` for v6 I had to [patch .rng validation](https://github.com/ovnicraft/web-addons/blob/master/web_field_style/server-view.rng.patch). I don't think that module has been ported to v8 or v9 (see [OCA web repo](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/8.0)), so I think you have 2 options:

1. port the module
2. use a wrapper div with a custom class  (yes, you can write HTML into form views), see example below

   <div class="bla">
       <field name="start_date" colspan="2" class="foo" />
   </div>

In this example the class "foo" on the field will be stripped out but the wrapping div with class "bla" will stay there ;)

Comment: Alright, this is the closest I've been so far. However, with this wrapper      <div class="oe_form_required"><field name="floor"/></div>                                 the name of the field has disappeared and left me only with a selection box...

Comment: labels appear only if the field is contained into a <group /> element. Still, you can add it explicitly with <label for="fname" /> tag

Comment: Again closer (let me clarify that this field is/was already contained in a <group/>), but now the label's font appears differently from the rest **and** (more importantly) it has destroyed the formatting (i.e. the selection box is now below the label).